# Python Backup script not working on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a backup script that creates zip of folders. This script is working on linux but not on Windows. Please help.

```
import os
import time

source = 'D:\\backup_original'

target_dir = 'E:\\backup_copied'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip {0} {1}".format(target, ''.join(source))


os.system(zip_command)
```

Comment: What's the traceback? I guess you don't have a `zip` command on Windows.

Comment: What not use the `gzip` module in the standard library?

Comment: I think gzip is not installed by default on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, zip is not installed by default. You need to install 7 zip, command line. I have modified your script.

```
import os
import time

source = 'D:\\backup_original'

target_dir = 'E:\\backup_copied'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "7za a {0} {1}".format(target, ''.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Backup Failed')
```

Are you sure this script was working on linux? u have used "zip a"? You must have copied it from somewhere.

Comment: @thanks. Yes I copied the zip line. I also tried to use 7zip earlier, but as u said, I didn't installed the command line.